# Eclipse RCP cancel job with InterruptedException

Tags: eclipse, rcp, jobs, interrupted-exception

Is it possible in Eclipse RCP 3.7 to cancel a long-running Job with InterruptedException?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of handling Job cancellation is for the implementation of the Job to periodically check `IProgressMonitor.isCanceled()` using the progress monitor passed into the job.  If `isCanceled()` returns true, you should return from the Job with `return Status.CANCEL_STATUS`.

That being said, you can throw an exception, but Eclipse's error handler will then display an error message.  Usually, this is not what you want.

Also, the last thing you want to do is to kill off the job thread because it's shared among the Jobs running in your RCP application.

Comment: Thank you Jed, I thought there is a way to say Eclipse to interrupt() the thread when the Cancel button is pressed, so I could interrupt some hanging connection requests which I cannot control myself. Now I see it is impossible.